# R- compare lmer with mice imputation to original data

Tags: r, imputation

I want to fit a mixed model with data containing missing values.

The imputation is performed with `mice`.
How can I compare the original data model fit to the mice one?
Example code..

```
## dummy data

set.seed(123)

DF <- data.frame(countryname = rep(LETTERS[1:10],each = 10), x1 = sample(10,100,replace = T),x2 = sample(5,100,replace = T), y = sample(10,100,replace = T))

# impute NAs
DF[sample(100,10),c("x1")] <- NA
DF[sample(100,10),c("x2")] <- NA
DF[sample(100,10),c("y")] <- NA

#

library(mice)

imp = mice(data = DF, m = 10, printFlag = FALSE)

fit = with(imp, expr=lme4::lmer(y~  x1+x2+ (1 | countryname)))

library(broom.mixed)

pool(fit) 
summary(fit)

## fit to original data


fitor= lme4::lmer(y~  x1+x2+ (1 | countryname),data=DF)

## how to compare model estimates for fit and fitor?
```

```
## example output

## 
## =======================================
##              base          w/SES       
## ---------------------------------------
## (Intercept)     0.105        -0.954 ***
##                (0.058)       (0.085)   
## x1        -0.497 ***    -0.356 ***
##                (0.058)       (0.054)   
## x2        -0.079        -0.102 *  
##                (0.043)       (0.040)   

## ---------------------------------------
## R2              0.039         0.157    
## Nobs         4073          4073        
## =======================================
## *** p < 0.001, ** p < 0.01, * p < 0.05

###
```

Comment: What type of comparison do you want to do exactly? Do you want to compare estimates from a model that just drops missing data rather than imputing? If you are asking for suggestions on how to evaulate your model fit, you should instead ask at [stats.se]. Questions here should be specific programming questions and should have a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Yes i want to compare the estimates of the model terms, to see  how they change when using data with imputations. I update my example code to include some dummy data

Comment: What's wrong with comparing `pool(fit)` to `summary(fitor)` ?

Comment: I am looking for a nice output like the ones obtained with stargazer or texreg.

Comment: So the question is just about formatting output? Again, it's really not clear what you mean when you say you want to "compare" the results. What exactly is the desired output?

Comment: made another update with example output